# Show that $\int_{x=a}^{x=b} f'(x) g(x) dx=f(b)g(b)-f(a)g(a)-\int_{x=a}^{x=b} g'(x)f(x)\, dx$

Tags: real-analysis, proof-writing

I have to prove the following:

Suppose $f$ and $g$ are differentiable on $[a,b]$ and $f'$ and $g'$ are integrable on $[a,b]$. Prove that $f'g$ and $g'f$ are integrable on $[a,b]$ and that of:

$$
\int_{x=a}^{x=b} f'(x) g(x)\, dx=f(b)g(b)-f(a)g(a)-\int_{x=a}^{x=b} g'(x)f(x)\, dx
$$

But I don't know how to prove that  $f'g$ is differentiable because I don't know if $U(fg,P)=U(f,P)+U(g,P)$, and the same thing for $L(fg,P)$, and  if I have to use the change variable theorem because I am not allowed to use it, I think there must be an easier way to get the result. Can you help me to prove this please? Thank you.

Comment: Maybe $f'g=f'g'-fg'$ and then the fundamental theorem of calculus

Comment: I think $f'g-g'f$ :), and the other part how you do it ? is beacuase it is a little confusing :)

Comment: Think about the product rule. $(fg)'=f'g'=f'g+fg'$. Now how can you rearrange this to find a relation for the integrand

Comment: Yes integrating both sides ;) isnt ?

Comment: Yea in a sense. Just replace $f'g$ by what I wrote in my first comment. Using the linearity of integration split up the sum and then use the fundamental theorem of calculus on $f'g'$

Comment: Ok let me check and i'll tell you if I get stuck

Comment: why do you have $x=a$ and $x=b$ for the limits of the integral? I just haven't seen that notation before and wondering why and in which branch or location in the world it is used.

Comment: Im sorry is just notation of latex that I found at Internet, and I am in Mexico at the University of Colima :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$\int_{x=a}^{x=b} f'(x) g(x)\, dx=g(x)f(x)|_{a}^{b}-\int_a^bg'(x)f(x)dx$$ (by integration of parts). This gives your answer.

It suffices to prove the statement: if $f$ is integrable on $[a,b]$ then so is $f^2$, then $fg=\dfrac{1}{2}((f+g)^2−f^2−g^2)$is integrable. To show that $f^2$ is integrable use the following:
$$\begin{align}U(f^2, P) - L(f^2,P) &= \sum (M_i^2 - m_i^2)\Delta x_i \\&< 2M \sum (M_i-m_i)\Delta x_i\\&= 2M(U(f,P) - L(f,P)) \\&<2M\frac{\varepsilon }{2M} = \varepsilon\end{align}$$

Here $M=\sup\limits_{[a,b]} f(x)$. So $f^2$ is integrable.

Comment: Thank you but we havent seen that at Analysis class :(

Comment: An how can I prove the product of two riemann integrable functions is integrable ? thnks :)

Comment: @user162343, did you skip a prerequisite for the course...?

Comment: No but I dont think we may use it if we havent seen the change variable thorem :)

Comment: well I think the product rule of diferentiation may help isnt ?

Comment: @user162343 Do you know about composition of functions and riemann integrability?

Comment: No only sum :) and scalar multiplication :)

Comment: @user162343 see the answer now

Comment: Ok let me check :)

Answer (score 1):

To prove that $fg'$ is integrable, use the fact that $fg' = \frac{1}{4}[(f + g')^2 - (f-g')^2].$ Use this to show $f'g$ is integrable as well.

The identity you wrote is just integration by parts. The transformation is given by, $u = g(x)$ and $dv = f'(x) dx$.